# PowerShell Adding "-" between every third char in string

Tags: powershell, shell, terminal, powershell-2.0

Hello I'm new with PowerShell. I have a string that I'm trying to add an "-" between every third char.

```
00255D413701 -> 00-25-5D-41-37-01
```

Anyone has an idea how to do this the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=\G.{2})(?!$)` might do the trick using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator):

```
'00255D413701' -replace '(?<=\G.{2})(?!$)', '-'
```

See https://regex101.com/r/MWOSie/1 for details.

Comment: Alternative: `([regex]::Matches('00255D413701','(..)')).Value -join '-'`